# Select and get data from filtered "checkedListBox"

Tags: c#

I'm new to c# so excuse the sloppy coding.
I got data that I'm implementing in to a checkedListBox by clicking a button. I'm using a textBox for a dynamic filter function.

```
        string loc_ShortNamesAndPIDs_S22 = "";
        service22Items = new DataTable();
        service22Items.Columns.Add("Service22");

        for (int i = 0; i < loc_Service22Infos.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
            loc_ShortNamesAndPIDs_S22 = "[" + loc_Service22Infos[i].variant + "] PID "
                                        + loc_Service22Infos[i].parameterId_hex
                                        + ": " + loc_Service22Infos[i].shortName;
            //checkedListBox_Service22Data.Items.Add(loc_ShortNamesAndPIDs_S22);
            service22Items.Rows.Add(loc_ShortNamesAndPIDs_S22);
            }

        checkedListBox_Service22Data.DataSource = ReutrnService22Items();
        checkedListBox_Service22Data.DisplayMember = "Service22";
        }

        private DataTable ReutrnService22Items()
        {
        return service22Items;
        }
```

So after I put the data into my checkedListBox I'm using the following code for the filter:

```
    private void srchBoxItems_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DataView dvNumbers = service22Items.DefaultView;
       dvNumbers.RowFilter = "Service22 LIKE '%" + srchBoxItems.Text + "%'";
    }
```

So now I'm able to Filter my Data, the only Problem I got, when I'm checking the check boxes to selected the Data I want to and filter everything it unchecks the check boxes. 
Therefore I was thinking to store the already checked indices and check them again (just a part of the code)...

```
       List<int> checkedList = new List<int>();
        serviceForm.ShowDialog();
        this.Show();
        for (int checkedItems_Counter = 0; checkedItems_Counter < checkedListBox_Service22Data.CheckedIndices.Count; checkedItems_Counter++)
        {
            checkedList.Add(checkedItems_Counter);
            checkedList.ToArray();
```

but that doesn't work because when you filter the data, the data that had the indices, lets say 56, will have the indices 1.

So my questions are:

Is there a way to keep the check boxes checked even though I'm filtering? I couldn't find anything...If yes this would be already the solution.

If not, ist there maybe a more elegant way to implement a dynamic filter that doesn't come with such a problem.

Is there a possibility to keep the indices that the data has when it is uploaded into the checkedListBox for the first time. Is there an elegant way or do I have to add an indices variable?

If there are any further questions please let me know and thanks in advance for your help!